# Chrome getting stuck on this jquery code, FF is fine

Tags: jquery

I have a page where I load several images from wikipedia. Wikipedia images have a filepath which you have to calculate from the filename, and which you then have to append to the following: `http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/`.

There are two problems.

1. In a minority of pictures, the url has `/en/` instead of `/commons/'`, but there's no way to know when.
2. Some of the links are outdated and don't return any image, leaving me with an ugly container div.

So I first try to load the image with `commons` and wrote some code which checks if the image gives an error. If it does, it replaces the `commons` with `en`. Then, if the image STILL gives an error (meaning the picture doesn't exist at all) the code replaces the entire src with `''` and hides the div.

All this works great with FF, but it crashes in Chrome. I get endless `jquery.min.js:2    Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` errors. If anyone could tell me what the problem is with my code and help me fix it I'd really appreciate it!

Here's the code:

```
$('#imgid').error(function()
{
   $(this).one("error", function() {
         $(this).attr('src','');$(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
  }).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace("/commons/", "/en/"));

});
```

TIA!

EDIT: The html surrounding the image looks like this:

```
<div data-id="7551400" class="pin">
<div id="sc7551400" class="scrol">
 <a class="PinIm" target="_blank" name="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Cage_de_Faraday.jpg" href="">
   <img class="PinImageImg" alt="" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Cage_de_Faraday.jpg/155px-Cage_de_Faraday.jpg" style="width:155px" id="img-7551400">
    </a>
       </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Can you chow the HTML to get what is the `parent().parent().parent()` element ? You might want to use `.parents(SELECTOR)`

Comment: Added the html to the question.

Comment: What if you try `$(this).parents('.pin').hide();` instead of `$(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();`

Comment: @PhilippeBoissonneault I don't mind trying, but why do you think that Chrome would have a problem with `$(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();`? My assumption was that there's something in the function that Chrome has a problem with.

Comment: what is #imgid an ID of?  You can only use an ID one time on a page, it sounds like you have multiple images with the same ID?  Also, when you call the $(this).one that can only happen once, maybe this is breaking when you have more than one error?

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of the `attr('src', $(this).attr('src'...`

Try this:

```
$('#imgid').error(function()
{
   var src = $(this).attr('src');
   $(this).one("error", function() {
      $(this).attr('src','');
      $(this).parents('.pin').hide();
   }).attr('src', src.replace("/commons/", "/en/"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are putting Chrome in an infinite loop trying to replace the src.  I would suggest something like this:

```
$('img').error(function()
{  
    if(this.errorCount == undefined) this.errorCount = 0;
    if(this.errorCount < 1){
        var newSource = $(this).attr('src').replace("/en/", "/commons/");
        $(this).attr('src', newSource);
     }
    if(this.errorCount == 1){
        $(this).parents('div').hide();
    }

    this.errorCount++;
});
```

this will set an errorcount to 0 and after the 1st time through it will hide the div.  You could use this to go through a couple of options if need be.

here is a fiddle where I changed the commons to common, so it will error twice, the second time through the div gets hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/davidstetler/uvKvC/